# I start a project to know more about google sign in and only add my app to my projects settings.py.Then i try to migrate, throws an error like

Tags: django, django-models, django-allauth

```
from django.utils import importlib
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'importlib' from 'django.utils'

Comment: Unless you give some more information and code I can't give you a good answer, but from what I know if you are using django version >=1.9 then this import won't work and you should change it to 'import importlib'

Comment: only type this code.    'django.contrib.sites',


    'admins',
    #allauth

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

    #providers
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
]
and also include the path in urls.py